# google cloud endpoints works on localhost but not when deployed to the app server

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following the [Web (JavaScript) Client Tutorial for creating Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/) using maven approach and I have successfully deployed it on my localhost and on the app server. The problem is that when I try to submit 0 or 1 in the get greetings form, I don't get any data. And this is working on the localhost but not on the deployed server. I debugged it with Firefox and it seems that it can't generate the API and fetch the data from there

```
GET https://myapp-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/helloworld/v1/rpc [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 96ms]
```

and when I click the button it returns me:

```
TypeError: gapi.client.helloworld is undefined
```

So I tried to open the link but it opens me a page error: Not Found

But when I run it on the localhost, everything is okay there and the link is working and it is displaying a big JSON message. I tried with the tictactoe sample also where everything is configured so I just changed the IDs but when I come to this part again I get the same error.
Does anyone knows what is the reason?

And also when I go to the APIs explorer it displays Loading and nothing loads..

Comment: I solved this by going to Google Cloud Console -> my app -> APP Engine -> Versions -> there setting the version to default and it worked for me.

Comment: Tip: when you want to enforce a version without setting it to default just use a url in the following format:
https://<version>-dot-<apptid>.appspot.com/_ah/api